# How can I write text into file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am new to C#. How can I write data into one file? This is my code so far:

```
public void convertHTML(string strData, string strTitle)
    {
        int position = strTitle.LastIndexOf('.');   
        strTitle = strTitle.Remove(position);
        strTitle= strTitle + ".html";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strTitle);   //strTitle is FilePath
        sw.WriteLine("<html>");
        sw.WriteLine("<head><title>{0}</title></head>",strTitle);
       //MessageBox.Show("this editor");
        sw.WriteLine("<body>");
        sw.WriteLine(strData);   //strData is having set of lines
        sw.WriteLine("</body>");
        sw.WriteLine("</html>");//*/
        lstHtmlFile.Items.Add(strTitle);
    }
```

it will simply create one blank html file it won't have any data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add block using in order to clean your `non managed object`

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(strTitle))
{

 ....
}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to flush and close the `StreamWriter`:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strTitle))
{

    sw.WriteLine("<html>");
    sw.WriteLine("<head><title>{0}</title></head>",strTitle);
    sw.WriteLine("<body>");
    sw.WriteLine(strData);
    sw.WriteLine("</body>");
    sw.WriteLine("</html>");
}
```

Using `using` does the trick.